# What means / happens when using the `INNER JOIN` with multiple database table statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and MySQL. I have a method (an `has_many :through` `ActiveRecord::Associations`) that generates the following SLQ query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `articles`.*
           FROM `articles`
     INNER JOIN `articles_comments_associations` `comment_associations_articles`
             ON `comment_associations_articles`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`
     INNER JOIN `articles_comments_associations`
             ON `articles`.`id` = `articles_comments_associations`.`article_id`
          WHERE `articles_comments_associations`.`comment_id` = 223
            AND (articles_comments_associations.user_id IN (2))
```

I would like to understand what it means `INNER JOIN 'articles_comments_associations' 'comment_associations_articles'` (*note*: there are multiple database table statements for the `INNER JOIN`) and how it is possible that the SQL query works since *I do not have a database table named `comment_associations_articles`*. **Is it an error** (even if it works as expected)**?**

Comment: Never use select *, that is a SQL antipattern, you should always specify the fields you want or you are wasting server and network resources particularly when you have joins where the join fields are repeated for no reason at all.

Comment: @HLGEM First, the SQL is generated by Rails, so without tweaking, that's what will happen. Second, it's only an anti-pattern if you don't need all the params *and* have complete control over SQL generation. Not saying `select *` is *preferred*, your point is well-taken.

Comment: If you don't have control over what fields are returned than you should not be using that ORM to generate the code. This is serious performance issue that is totally due to developer laziness. Efficeint queries are critical to database systems, if the ORM can't write them, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: And if you have a join of any type you do not need all the fields by definition.

Comment: @HLGEM Feel free to contribute a Rails patch and/or re-write AR; I'm sure they'd appreciate it--I know I would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a table alias.  Meaning, it is renaming the table `articles_comments_associations` to `comment_associations_articles` for the purpose of further references in the query.  Any field or table can be aliased by simply giving another name following the table/field reference.

Comment: The alias is probably generated automatically by RoR because the same table is used twice in the same query, so the table has to be aliased in order to reference the two instances separately.  The actual alias handling is a MySQL feature (and a feature of most RDBMS systems).

Comment: And why it executes 2 `INNER JOIN`? Should those have the same "effect" / "result"?

Comment: Actually that's a good point, it does appear they do the same thing.  I don't see the purpose of including the same table twice, since the one is never even referenced.  There's probably some generic logic in RoR that isn't very optimized for your scenario and so is generating extraneous code.  There are, however, real and good reasons to join the same table twice in practice, such as when you have a hierarchical relationship (parent-child) between the records in the same table, or you need to link by two separate relationships.