# Is it possible to "dynamically" join a table only if that table is not joined yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, conditional-statements

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if in scope methods it is possible to "dynamically" join a table only if that table is not joined yet. That it, I have:

```
def self.scope_method_name(user)
  joins(:joining_association_name).where("joining_table_name.user_id = ?", user.id)
end
```

I would like to make something like the following:

```
# Note: the following code is just a sample in order to understand what I mean.
def self.scope_method_name(user)
  if table_is_joined?(joining_table_name)
    where("joining_table_name.user_id = ?", user.id)
  else
    joins(:joining_association_name).where("joining_table_name.user_id = ?", user.id)
  end
end
```

**Is it possible / advised to make that? If so, how could / should I proceed?**

---

I would like to use this approach in order to avoid [multiple database table statements in `INNER JOIN` of SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210241/what-means-happens-when-using-the-inner-join-with-multiple-database-table-st/11210262#11210262) (*in some cases it seems to make my SQL querying not working as expected since multiple table statements*) and so to use the `scope_method_name` without caring related SQL query concerns (in my case, without caring to join database tables).

*Note*: It could raise SQL errors (for example, errors as-like "`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'joining_table_name.user_id' in 'where clause'`") when you have *not joined yet* the database table (for example, this could happen when you run code like `ClassName.scope_method_name(@user)` *without to previously join* the `joining_association_name` and so without to join the related `joining_table_name` table).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Where is the method `loaded?` to check if an association has been loaded. You could try to use that.

```
if association_name.loaded?
   where("joining_table_name.user_id = ?", user.id)
else
   joins(:joining_association_name).where("joining_table_name.user_id = ?", user.id)
end
```

Comment: Will your code avoid SQL errors (for example, errors as-like "You have an error in your SQL statement: table `joining_table_name` is not specified in the SQL query or that table doesn't exist in the database") when you have *not joined yet* the database table (for example, this could happen when you run code like `ClassName.scope_method_name(@user)` *without to previously* join the `joining_association_name` and so without to join the related `joining_table_name` table)?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you are trying to use a scope. `association_name.loaded?` would only be available to an instance. Can't answer your question... but rails should take care of not loading an association twice.

Comment: It seems that Rails doesn't care "of not loading an association twice", at least in the case of the [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210241/what-means-happens-when-using-the-inner-join-with-multiple-database-table-st?lq=1) (read comments).

Comment: Well... it depends if the extra association is such a huge performance issue. I wonder if there is any benchmark on this.